# Slow updating of Intent.EXTRA_TEXT [due to incorrect use of Strings

Tags: java, android, android-intent, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

**EDIT:** *Changed the title of this post as that the issue was due to the incorrect use of String concatenation.*

I'm sure Im needlessly complicating this but I'm having issues dynamically updating my `intent` for use in the `ShareActionProvider`.

The Documentation says that I don't need to worry about onClick since the `ShareActionProvider` takes care of this, however, I only want to build the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` when the user clicks the `ActionProvider`.

The reason I don't want to update the intent interactively is because it takes about 2000ms to build the extra information for the intent and the user can work relatively faster causing the UI to become sluggish.

I'm sure I can sit down and figure out how to use AsyncTask to build the Intent in the background, but that seems a little overkill.

I've tried `setOnShareTargetSelectedListener`and `onPrepareSubMenu`and a number of other callbacks, but they all seem to be called after the intent is passed on and it takes two presses of the Action Provider before the information is up to date.

Some code; This is called to build my Intent:

```
public void buildIntent(){
    if (mShareIntent == null)
        return;
    mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Start:" + mAddressArray.get(0) + " Span:" + (mAddressArray.get(1)-mAddressArray.get(0)));

    buildHTML bh = new buildHTML(mAddressArray, mBitArray);

    mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bh.getText());
    //mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, bh.getHTML());
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent);

}
```

The things that slows everything down is the `bh.getText();`

```
public class buildHTML {
  private ArrayList<Integer> mAddress;
  private ArrayList<String> mBits;

  buildHTML(ArrayList<Integer> address, ArrayList<String> bits){
    mAddress = address;
    mBits = bits;
  }

  public String getText(){
    String str;
    str = "DMX : ADDRESS  \n";
    str += "--- : ---------\n";
    int count = mAddress.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) //takes up to 3000ms to run
       str += String.format("%03d : %s\n", mAddress.get(i), mBits.get(i));
    return str;
    }
```

All I'm trying to do is run `buildIntent()` when the user clicks on the ShareActionProvider so that the intent gets send to the activity.

Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question with some help from and Android gods.

Basically the reason that my Intent building was taking so long was because every time I did a  string concatenation (str +=) the buffer needed to be enlarged (I should have know that).

With a little guidance I used the DDMS Profiler to dig into the problem:

[image: Don't do str += ever again.]

I then decided to use a `StringBuilder` object initialized to the size of the Extra Intent information and BAM, The intent takes less then 17ms to build now in it's worse case.

For those learning like me I changed this:

```
public String getText(){
String str;
str = "DMX : ADDRESS  \n";
str += "--- : ---------\n";
int count = mAddress.size();

for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) //takes up to 3000ms to run
   str += String.format("%03d : %s\n", mAddress.get(i), mBits.get(i));
return str;
}
```

to this:

```
public String getText(){
    int count = mAddress.size();

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder((count+2)*16);

    str.append("DMX : ADDRESS  \n"); //16
    str.append("--- : ---------\n"); //16

    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
        str.append(String.format("%03d : %s\n", mAddress.get(i), mBits.get(i)));
    return str.toString();
```